# log4j2 not logging to console (please don't mark as duplicate, i have tried the other suggested solutions)

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I'm changing the current code that uses log4j to log4j2 and I'm experiencing difficulty getting the logs to be printed to the console. I have excluded the spring framework boot logging dependencies. I have added trace status to my log4j2.properties and I can see that the code is able to find the log4j2.properties file. There was code to reconfigure the log using the properties file that I changed to how it should be done in log4j2. I have pasted that code below and the trace output. I'm not sure what else to try. I read on one of the answers that the logger might be getting shut down so I set shutdownHook=disable to see if that could fix it. There was also this post about the file not being in the classpath. the java code looks for the file in another directory and I can see from the trace output that it can find it. what could be the reason for the logs not printing?

code

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(StealthServices.class);

System.out.println("file name: " + args[1]);
final LoggerContext context = LoggerContext.getContext(false);
File file = new File(args[1]);
context.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
context.reconfigure();
```

trace output

```
    WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,514 main DEBUG null null initializing configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@45c7e403
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,525 main DEBUG Took 0.008063 seconds to load 1 plugins from package mnav
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,525 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 128 plugins
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,525 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,527 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,528 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,538 main TRACE TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,538 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 26 plugins
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,543 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="stdout", level="null", Filter=null)
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,543 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,549 main DEBUG LoggerConfig$RootLogger$Builder(additivity="null", level="DEBUG", levelAndRefs="null", includeLocation="null", ={stdout}, ={}, Configuration, Filter=null)
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,550 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,551 main DEBUG createLoggers(={root})
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,551 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,552 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d %-5p %c %x %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration, Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,552 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 45 plugins
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,558 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,564 main DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="null", follow="null", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d %-5p %c %x %m%n), name="stdout", Configuration, Filter=null, ={})
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,566 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,567 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,567 main DEBUG createAppenders(={stdout})
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,567 main DEBUG Configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@45c7e403 initialized
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,568 main DEBUG Starting configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@45c7e403
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,568 main DEBUG Started configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@45c7e403 OK.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,568 main TRACE Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@776aec5c...
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,568 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,569 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,569 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,569 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,569 main DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-4
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,569 main DEBUG OutputStream closed
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,570 main DEBUG Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-4, all resources released: true
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,570 main DEBUG Appender DefaultConsole-4 stopped with status true
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,570 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,570 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,570 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@776aec5c OK
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,571 main TRACE Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@31e5415e
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,571 main TRACE Reregistering context (1/1): '8bcc55f' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@a2431d0
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,571 main TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f]
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,572 main TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=StatusLogger]
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,572 main TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=ContextSelector]
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,572 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=Loggers,name=*'
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,573 main TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=Appenders,name=DefaultConsole-2]
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,573 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,573 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,574 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,574 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,574 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=StatusLogger
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,575 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=ContextSelector
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,575 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=Appenders,name=DefaultConsole-2
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,576 main TRACE Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,576 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=Default] at URI /home/stealthadmin/Desktop/DMRI/stealthapplication/ApplicationHome/share/config/logger/StealthServices.log4j2.properties (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@702b8b12) with optional ClassLoader: null
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,576 main DEBUG Reconfiguration started for context[name=Default] at URI file:/home/stealthadmin/Desktop/DMRI/stealthapplication/ApplicationHome/release_env/share/config/logger/StealthServices.log4j2.properties (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@702b8b12) with optional ClassLoader: null
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,576 main DEBUG Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@22e357dc
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,577 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,578 main DEBUG null null initializing configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@49912c99
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,578 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 128 plugins
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,579 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,579 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,579 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,580 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="stdout", level="null", Filter=null)
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,580 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,581 main DEBUG LoggerConfig$RootLogger$Builder(additivity="null", level="DEBUG", levelAndRefs="null", includeLocation="null", ={stdout}, ={}, Configuration, Filter=null)
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,581 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,581 main DEBUG createLoggers(={root})
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,582 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,582 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d %-5p %c %x %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration, Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,582 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 45 plugins
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,583 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,584 main DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="null", follow="null", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d %-5p %c %x %m%n), name="stdout", Configuration, Filter=null, ={})
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,585 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,586 main DEBUG createAppenders(={stdout})
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,586 main DEBUG Configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@49912c99 initialized
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,586 main DEBUG Starting configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@49912c99
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,586 main DEBUG Started configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@49912c99 OK.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,587 main TRACE Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@45c7e403...
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,587 main TRACE PropertiesConfiguration notified 2 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,587 main TRACE PropertiesConfiguration stopping 1 LoggerConfigs.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,587 main TRACE PropertiesConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,587 main TRACE PropertiesConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,588 main TRACE PropertiesConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,588 main DEBUG Appender stdout stopped with status true
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,588 main TRACE PropertiesConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,588 main TRACE PropertiesConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 2 LoggerConfigs.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,588 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@45c7e403 OK
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,589 main TRACE Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@31e5415e
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,589 main TRACE Reregistering context (1/1): '8bcc55f' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@a2431d0
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,589 main TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f]
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,590 main TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=StatusLogger]
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,590 main TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=ContextSelector]
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (jar:file:/opt/mnav/share/tractography/bin/server-main-1.0.0.CR3.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar!/) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,590 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=Loggers,name=*'
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,591 main TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=Appenders,name=DefaultConsole-2]
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,591 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,591 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,591 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,592 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,592 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=StatusLogger
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,592 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=ContextSelector
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,593 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=Appenders,name=DefaultConsole-2
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,593 main TRACE Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
    2022-06-27 14:19:36,593 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=Default] at URI /home/stealthadmin/Desktop/DMRI/stealthapplication/ApplicationHome/share/config/logger/StealthServices.log4j2.properties (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@702b8b12) with optional ClassLoader: null
```

log4j2.properties

```
packages=mnav
status=trace
shutdownHook=disable


appender.console.name = stdout
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=%d %-5p %c %x %m%n

rootLogger.level=debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = stdout
```

debug output

```
 WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
2022-06-29 08:59:57,063 main DEBUG null null initializing configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@752325ad
2022-06-29 08:59:57,076 main DEBUG Took 0.010724 seconds to load 1 plugins from package mnav
2022-06-29 08:59:57,076 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 128 plugins
2022-06-29 08:59:57,077 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2022-06-29 08:59:57,078 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
2022-06-29 08:59:57,079 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2022-06-29 08:59:57,088 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 26 plugins
2022-06-29 08:59:57,094 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="stdout", level="null", Filter=null)
2022-06-29 08:59:57,094 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
2022-06-29 08:59:57,099 main DEBUG LoggerConfig$RootLogger$Builder(additivity="null", level="DEBUG", levelAndRefs="null", includeLocation="null", ={stdout}, ={}, Configuration, Filter=null)
2022-06-29 08:59:57,100 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
2022-06-29 08:59:57,101 main DEBUG createLoggers(={root})
2022-06-29 08:59:57,102 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2022-06-29 08:59:57,103 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d %-5p %c %x %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration, Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2022-06-29 08:59:57,104 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 45 plugins
2022-06-29 08:59:57,111 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
2022-06-29 08:59:57,116 main DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="null", follow="null", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d %-5p %c %x %m%n), name="stdout", Configuration, Filter=null, ={})
2022-06-29 08:59:57,118 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
2022-06-29 08:59:57,119 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
2022-06-29 08:59:57,119 main DEBUG createAppenders(={stdout})
2022-06-29 08:59:57,120 main DEBUG Configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@752325ad initialized
2022-06-29 08:59:57,120 main DEBUG Starting configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@752325ad
2022-06-29 08:59:57,120 main DEBUG Started configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@752325ad OK.
2022-06-29 08:59:57,120 main DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-4
2022-06-29 08:59:57,121 main DEBUG OutputStream closed
2022-06-29 08:59:57,121 main DEBUG Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-4, all resources released: true
2022-06-29 08:59:57,121 main DEBUG Appender DefaultConsole-4 stopped with status true
2022-06-29 08:59:57,121 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@175c2241 OK
2022-06-29 08:59:57,122 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f
2022-06-29 08:59:57,123 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=StatusLogger
2022-06-29 08:59:57,123 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=ContextSelector
2022-06-29 08:59:57,124 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=8bcc55f,component=Appenders,name=DefaultConsole-2
2022-06-29 08:59:57,124 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=Default] at URI /home/stealthadmin/Desktop/DMRI/stealthapplication/ApplicationHome/share/config/logger/StealthServices.log4j2.properties (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@649bec2e) with optional ClassLoader: null
```

Comment: _"sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported"_: in your case it means that Log4j2 can not detect the classloader of the caller and the logger context you configure is not necessarily the one use by your classes. What version of Log4j2 are you using and how do you run your application?

Comment: i am using the lo4j core 2.17.2 and the API 2.17.2 versions. i have also added the log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.2, log4j-jul-2.17.2 and commons-logging-api-1.1 dependencies according to this link https://people.apache.org/~rgoers/log4j2/faq.html#which_jars. the Java class for this logger is the main class that calls a number of other components to start the application. I have a makefile that uses all of the jar files and adds the dependencies to the main project jar file when the code is compiled.

Comment: i looked this error up and https://discourse.metabase.com/t/warning-sun-reflect-reflection-getcallerclass-is-not-supported-this-will-impact-performance/12130 says that it can be ignored.

Comment: the code I added above are the only places I have used log manager and loggerContext and then throughout the rest of the code, log.info log.error etc are called to print to the logs. I wanted to point out that in this migration I have yet to reconfigure the XML files for all the different components to be compatible with log4j2. Since there are more than 40 of those files, I wanted to make sure my updates were working in the main class before making those other changes. I don't think this would break it since any code regarding the logger for this class has been updated to log4j2 syntax

Comment: The warning about `sun.reflect.Reflection`, when running on Java 9+, means that whatever you are using to start your application, does not support multi-release JARs. Since `Reflection` or its Java 9+ equivalent are used to find the caller's class, your `log` might be attached to a different logger context than the one you configure. Can you run the application with `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` and add the complete status logger output?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I just updated the post with the debug output. thanks for your help. I also did a search for the <Multi-Release> tag and both my log4j-core and log4j-api jar files that are eventually added into my main jar file, have that tag set to true

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz i fixed it. you were right about the logger context. I decided to use this method definition of get context (LoggerContext getContext(final ClassLoader loader, final boolean currentContext,  final URI configLocation) and added {myclass}.class.getClassLoader()" to the first parameter and it finally started printing  to the console. thank you for your help!